# how can i implement subset in r in sas?

Tags: r, sas

[image]

Hi! 
There are two dfs that share a date column and an id column. `df_1` has one row for a particular id, and `df_2` has multiple rows for that id.
 In `df_2`, I want to extract the rows that match the ID of the first row of `df_1`, and then re-extract only rows less than the date in the first row of `df_1`.
I want to repeat this process for the entire row of `df_1`.
And I want to use rbind to bundle it into one piece of data.

the code in R

`df_3 <- data.frame()`

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df_1)){
    x <- subset(df_2, id == df_1[['id']][i])
    y <- subset(x, date < df_1[['date']][i])
    df_3 <- rbind(df_3, y)
}
```

how can i do this in sas?

please help me.

Comment: proc sql and a where statement

Comment: can you show me the code??

Comment: @박기찬 That is some *very* awkward R code. The `for` loop seems unnecessary, as do the two `subset` statements. If you (1) post some sample data, (2) describe the rules for subsetting the data, and (3) include your expected output based on the sample data, it would be easy to improve your R code first. That might also help with translating to SAS.

Comment: You're better off translating this to laymen terminology and explain with data. As posted you'd need to know both R and SAS, whereas if you post the details someone only needs to know SAS. In general, you don't want to do line by line translation of your code, you want to use the most efficient method in SAS to do whatever you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `proc iml` to implement the functionality, please see as below:

```
   proc iml;
/* id - first colum */
/* date - second column */

df_1 = {102 20180102, 103 20180105, 104 20180108};
df_2 = {102 20180101, 102 20180103, 103 20180103, 103 20180107,
        104 20180101, 104 20180102, 104 20180103};

free df_3;

do i = 1 to nrow(df_1);
  x = df_2[loc(df_2[, 1] = df_1[i, 1]), ];
  y = x[loc(x[, 2] < df_1[i, 2]), ];
  df_3 = df_3 // y;
end;

print df_1 df_2 df_3;
```

Output:

[image: SAS Output]